# obtaining xml node value in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign

I'm putting together a script for InDesign using javascript, and have a settings xml file from which I'd like to pull out a value of a particular node.

I've successfully read in the XML file

```
var xml = new XML(file.read());
```

and can easily pull attribute values / node lengths etc, however I'd like to pull the text inside a particular node.

```
<article>
    <title>This is the title</title>
</article>
```

I've tried `xml.article[0].title` but this returns an XML object not the vale. I've tried `nodeValue` to no success. How do I obtain the actual text?

Comment: How do you parse the xml? DomParser()?

Comment: using the XML class - E4X? Don't say it's deprecated because this is Adobe scripting not pure javascript!

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
xml.article[0].title.toString()
```

Answer (score -2):

Its very simple, just searching the stackoverflow should have given you the result

```
var sXML = "<article><title>This is the title</title></article>";
$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    var xmlDoc = $( sXML );
    xmlDoc.filter( 'article' ).each( function ()
    {
        alert( $( this ).find( 'title' ).text() );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Ha ha, slight miss understanding, yep you find out the answer good.